# Z order in between Image and InkPresenter

Tags: wpf, image, wpf-positioning

I have this CustomControl which contains an `InkPresenter` and an `Image`. The image has an `AdornerDecorator` as I plan to add an adorner to the image later on. I have set the `Canvas.ZIndex` of the `Image` to be higher than the `InkPresenter` so that the `InkPresenter` will be drawn over the Image.

The problem is that when I try to collect and display ink from the `InkPresenter` the strokes are drawn underneath the image. (I have used to check the visual tree using Snoop and the `InkPresenter` is above the `Image`) I'm not sure why this is. Does anyone here know why the `Image` is drawn on top of the `InkPresenter`? Any help is much appreciated.

My code is as follows:

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HotSpotImage">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HotSpotImage}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HotSpotImage}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <local:StringtoImageSource x:Key="ImageSourceConverter"/>

                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Canvas Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">    
                        <InkPresenter Canvas.ZIndex="1"  
                                      x:Name="PART_InkPresenter"
                                      Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                                      Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                        <Image Canvas.ZIndex="2"  x:Name="PART_Image" 
                               Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                               Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Source="{Binding 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                Path=Source, 
                                Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}}"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have attached the `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`, `MouseMove` etc events to the `InkPresenter` as I plan to move the handling of these events to other classes later on.

Unfortunately these events don't get captured because the `Image` is drawn on top of the `InkPresenter` so it gets the events rather than the `InkPresenter`. Does anyone know why this may be?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking about z-order backwards. The higher values are closer to the user, thus the image with value 2 is drawn over the ink with value 1.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980110(VS.95).aspx)